# Calculate Km with latitude and longitude of different DataFrames Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, data-analysis

I have 4 Dataframes (ticket_data.csv, providers.csv, stations.csv and cities.csv)

In stations.csv I have 2 colls called o_city (origin city) and d_city (destination city) those two colls gives me the id of the city i need to look for in cities.csv

In cities.csv I have the lat and long of each city.

How can i calculate the distance between o_city and d_city for each ticket ? I tried to use pyproj but I didn't find a way to make it work with each ticket..

Screenshot of csv files :

[ticket_data.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJn2I.png)

[cities.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy6wi.png)

Comment: Your question needs a bit of work, I suggest (a) post a small subsampl of your data as actual text in your question (so that we can use `pd.read_clipboard()`) to easily work with the data. (b) provide the exact output you want (at least the exact format if you don't know the numbers) and (c) define what distance metric you want to use as going from lat/long to distance in km is not a simple as euclidean (maybe you want Haversine).

Comment: Use `geopy.distance` to get distance between two GPS coords.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!  In your cities dataframe, assuming here it is called **city_df**; for each row you can use something called the haversine distance formula from Euclidean geometry to calculate the distance between two coordinate pairs on Earth's surface.  Here is an example of some dummy Python3 code of roughly how you may go about this (just using two pairs of coordinates for ease of communication):

```
from haversine import haversine

distance = haversine((city_df[origin_lat][0], city_df[origin_lon][0]), (city_df[destination_lat][0], city_df[destination_lon][0]))
```

The coordinates must be in decimal degree notation as in *43.9202* instead of 43* 38" 67' notation.  Given this, the output value of *distance* will be in km units.

Hope this helps you get closer to solving your problem!

*P. S. - you may need to install haversine, as it is not in the standard libary*

Comment: I'm sure it could help me but I don't know how to define my origin and destination lon / lat, i'm not really good at English so i'm going to try to explain my problem :

Comment: My mission is to get the average price difference and duration depending on the train, the bus and the carpooling depending on the distance of the journey (0-200km, 201-800km, 800-2000km, 2000 + km)

Each travel data is in the ticket_data.csv, but it doesn't give directly the lon and lat it gives me and id of the o_city and d_city and i dont know how to say for example:

origin_lon = the lon of the corresponding id of the city in cities.csv 

The first line of my ticket_data.csv gives me o_city = 611 how can i get a variable corresponding to the lat / lon of city 611 in cities.csv ?

Comment: You can read in each dataframe and then add the lat/lon columns from your cities.csv dataframe to your ticket_data.csv dataframe by doing something like ticket_data_df['LAT'] = cities_df['LAT'] ... and the same kind of thing for the longitude (assuming each dataframe is the same length).  You could achieve the same thing with this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: ticket_data is 74000 lines and cities is only 8000 lines and i can have a city with the number 12000, the id of the cities are random not auto incremented.. 
If i do ticket_data_df['LAT'] = cities_df['LAT'] would the lat of city number 611 be equal to the lat of the city with the id 611 or to the lat of the city that is on line 611 ?

Comment: To install haversine from Conda:  `conda install -c conda-forge haversine`